# Powershell Mass Rename files with a excel reference list

Tags: powershell

I need help with PowerShell.

I will have to start renaming files in a weekly basis which I will be renaming more than 100 a week or more  each with a dynamic name.

The files I want to rename are in a folder name ***Scans*** located in the "C: Documents\Scans". And they would be in order, to say time scanned.

I have an excel file located in "C: Documents\Mapping\ New File Name.xlsx.
The workbook has only one sheet and the new names would be in column A with x rows. Like mention above each cell will have different variables.

P Lease make comments on your suggestions so that I may understand what is going on since I'm a new to coding.

Thank you all for your time and help.

Comment: Can you show us (part of) the Excel content so we can see wether or not it contains full path and filenames or just names? What decides the _"dynamic name"_ ?

Comment: It would be the scanning, when scanning it save the files as Scan 1 and so on.

Comment: Just refer to the Scans Folder. The files scanned will be in order with the most recent scanned at the top. Lets say I scanned 100 and the one displaying at the top will be scan 100, scan 99, scan 98 and so on. And in the excel file in column A there will be 100 rows with each cell value containing unique values. I would need PowerShell to override the current file name with the  new name that is reference in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I agree with Ad Kasenally that it would be easier to use CSV files, here's something that may work for you.

```
$excelFile   = 'C:\Documents\Mapping\New File Name.xlsx'
$scansFolder = 'C:\Documents\Scans'

########################################################
# step 1: get the new filenames from the first column in
# the Excel spreadsheet into an array '$newNames'
########################################################
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false
$workbook  = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelFile)
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

$newNames = @()
$i = 1
while ($worksheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).Value() -ne $null) {
    $newNames += $worksheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).Value()
    $i++
}

$excel.Quit
# IMPORTANT: clean-up used Com objects
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($worksheet) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

########################################################
# step 2: rename the 'scan' files
########################################################
$maxItems = $newNames.Count
if ($maxItems) {
    $i = 0
    Get-ChildItem -Path $scansFolder -File -Filter 'scan*' |      # get a list of FileInfo objects in the folder
        Sort-Object { [int]($_.BaseName -replace '\D+', '') } |   # sort by the numeric part of the filename
        Select-Object -First ($maxItems) |                        # select no more that there are items in the $newNames array
        ForEach-Object {
            try {
                Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newNames[$i] -ErrorAction Stop
                Write-Host "File '$($_.Name)' renamed to '$($newNames[$i])'"
                $i++
            }
            catch {
                throw
            }
        }
}
else {
    Write-Warning "Could not get any new filenames from the $excelFile file.."
}
```

Comment: Thank you the code works perfectly sorry for the lag.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have 2 columns in the excel file:

- original file name
- target file name

From there you can save the file as a csv.

Use Import-Csv to pull the data into Powershell and a ForEach loop to cycle through each row with a command like move $item.original $item.target.

There are abundant threads describing using import-csv with forEach.

Good luck.